# how do you get default Kafka configs global and per topic from command line?

Tags: apache-kafka

How do you get default Kafka configs global and per topic from the command line or other ways?

I know the defaults are available on [Broker Configs](http://kafka.apache.org/081/documentation.html#brokerconfigs) and you can get per topic "overrides" using describe, but if I make many changes to topic level configuration, it would be nice to get all values including the overrides per topic.

```
$KAFKA_HOME/bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper $ZK --describe --topic test-topic
$KAFKA_HOME/bin/kafka-configs.sh --zookeeper $ZK --describe --entity-name test-topic --entity-type topics
```

FYI, I am just getting started with kafka v0.9.0.1.

Apparently, there is a [discussion about why this is not possible](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Dynamic+Topic+Config), so I guess there is no solution.

Comment: Guess, the solution if you do want to touch a config is to check global settings in ~/kafka/config/server.properties, then update Config:

`     > bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper zk_host:port/chroot --alter --topic my_topic_name --config x=y `


Then remove the topic config:

 `    > bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper zk_host:port/chroot --alter --topic my_topic_name --deleteConfig x `

As discussed it in https://kafka.apache.org/090/ops.html#basic_ops_modify_topic

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Since Kafka 2.5.0 (see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-9040), you can now use the `--all` option to see all (default and overridden) topic configuration:

```
% kafka-configs --bootstrap-server <KAFKA_SERVERS> --entity-type topics --entity-name <TOPIC_NAME> --describe --all
All configs for topic <TOPIC_NAME> are:
  compression.type=producer sensitive=false synonyms={}
  message.format.version=1.0-IV0 sensitive=false synonyms={}
  file.delete.delay.ms=60000 sensitive=false synonyms={}
  leader.replication.throttled.replicas= sensitive=false synonyms={}
  max.message.bytes=1000012 sensitive=false synonyms={}
  min.compaction.lag.ms=0 sensitive=false synonyms={}
  message.timestamp.type=CreateTime sensitive=false synonyms={}
  min.insync.replicas=1 sensitive=false synonyms={}
  segment.jitter.ms=0 sensitive=false synonyms={}
  preallocate=false sensitive=false synonyms={}
  index.interval.bytes=4096 sensitive=false synonyms={}
  min.cleanable.dirty.ratio=0.5 sensitive=false synonyms={}
  unclean.leader.election.enable=false sensitive=false synonyms={}
  retention.bytes=-1 sensitive=false synonyms={}
  delete.retention.ms=86400000 sensitive=false synonyms={}
  cleanup.policy=delete sensitive=false synonyms={}
  flush.ms=1000 sensitive=false synonyms={}
  follower.replication.throttled.replicas= sensitive=false synonyms={}
  segment.bytes=1073741824 sensitive=false synonyms={}
  retention.ms=172800000 sensitive=false synonyms={}
  segment.ms=604800000 sensitive=false synonyms={}
  message.timestamp.difference.max.ms=9223372036854775807 sensitive=false synonyms={}
  flush.messages=10000 sensitive=false synonyms={}
  segment.index.bytes=10485760 sensitive=false synonyms={}
```

As you can see in the [PR](https://github.com/apache/kafka/pull/7607/files), you can use this option for (at least) broker config too.

Also note that this option does **not** currently exist in `kafka-topics` CLI.

Answer (score 11):

You can get information about list of all topics present on your network with this command

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --list --zookeeper localhost:2181
```

For each topic you can get infos with:

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --describe --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic test
```

From the [Kafka documentation](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html):

> Here is an explanation of output. The first line gives a summary of
>   all the partitions, each additional line gives information about one
>   partition. Since we have only one partition for this topic there is
>   only one line.
>
> - "leader" is the node responsible for all reads and writes for the given partition. Each node will be the leader for a randomly selected
>     portion of the partitions.
> - "replicas" is the list of nodes that replicate the log for this partition regardless of whether they are the leader or even if they
>     are currently alive.
> - "isr" is the set of "in-sync" replicas. This is the subset of the replicas list that is currently alive and caught-up to the leader.

Comment: As I mentioned that we are aware of getting global only and then specific topic override settings separately. What I was trying to find is another simple option to get all of them per topic (with topic overrides) instead of us manually figuring that out especially where there are many overrides.

Comment: Was also trying to find a command line way of getting all global settings? Or no way to get a specific config value of a topic? https://kafka.apache.org/090/ops.html#basic_ops_modify_topic

Answer (score 11):

At least for newer versions of Kafka you can also query topic specific properties via command:

```
bin/kafka-configs.sh --describe --zookeeper localhost:2181 --entity-type topics --entity-name test
```

Comment: Yep, it has not changed since v0.9 as you can see in my question description. There is no way to get all properties at once for a topic, you have to get global properties and then topic properties and see them together :(

Comment: This doesn't seem to work when using the --bootstrap-server argument instead of the --zookeeper argument. It says "invalid entity-type topics" (Kafka 2.4.0 on Confluent Platform 5.4.1)

Answer (score 0):

in newer versions of kafka zookeeper connection is not needed, to modify topics just go to the broker, using `kafka-topics.sh` from https://kafka.apache.org/downloads

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --describe --bootstrap-server broker_url --topic test-topic

bin/kafka-topics.sh --list --bootstrap-server broker_url
```

Answer (score 0):

the new versions of kafka can't handle the proposed answers .
see new version :
https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#connectconfigs
use for new kafka version :
**bin/kafka-configs.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --entity-type topics --entity-name prefix.large.topicData --describe**

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to get the topic configs. One is via command line tool kafka-configs and the other is via REST Proxy API. Please see examples for both of them below.

**Using Kafka Config:**

```
    bin % ./kafka-configs --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --entity-type topics --entity-name tpmqtt --describe --all
    All configs for topic tpmqtt are:
      compression.type=producer sensitive=false synonyms={DEFAULT_CONFIG:compression.type=producer}
      confluent.tier.cleaner.compact.min.efficiency=0.5 sensitive=false synonyms={DEFAULT_CONFIG:confluent.tier.cleaner.compact.min.efficiency=0.5}
      confluent.value.schema.validation=false sensitive=false synonyms={}
      leader.replication.throttled.replicas= sensitive=false synonyms={}
      confluent.stray.log.max.deletions.per.run=72 sensitive=false synonyms={DEFAULT_CONFIG:confluent.stray.log.max.deletions.per.run=72}
      confluent.key.subject.name.strategy=io.confluent.kafka.serializers.subject.TopicNameStrategy sensitive=false synonyms={}
      message.downconversion.enable=true sensitive=false synonyms={DEFAULT_CONFIG:log.message.downconversion.enable=true}
      min.insync.replicas=1 sensitive=false synonyms={DEFAULT_CONFIG:min.insync.replicas=1}
............
............
............
```

**

**Using Rest Proxy:**

**

```
curl http://localhost:8082/topics/tpmqtt
{"name":"tpmqtt","configs":{"compression.type":"producer","confluent.tier.cleaner.compact.min.efficiency":"0.5","confluent.value.schema.validation":"false","leader.replication.throttled.replicas":"","confluent.stray.log.max.deletions.per.run":"72","confluent.key.subject.name.strategy":"io.confluent.kafka.serializers.subject.TopicNameStrategy","message.downconversion.enable":"true","min.insync.replicas":"1","segment.jitter.ms":"0","confluent.stray.log.delete.delay.ms":"604800000","confluent.tier.cleaner.enable":"false","confluent.compacted.topic.prefer.tier.fetch.ms":"-1","cleanup.policy":"delete","flush.ms":"9223372036854775807","confluent.tier.local.hotset.ms":"86400000","follower.replication.throttled.replicas":"","confluent.tier.local.hotset.bytes":"-1","confluent.value.subject.name.strategy":"io.confluent.kafka.serializers.subject.TopicNameStrategy","segment.bytes":"1073741824","retention.ms":"604800000","flush.messages":"9223372036854775807","confluent.tier.enable":"false","confluent.tier.segment.hotset.roll.min.bytes":"104857600","confluent.segment.speculative.prefetch.enable":"false","message.format.version":"3.0-IV1","confluent.min.segment.ms":"1","max.compaction.lag.ms":"9223372036854775807","confluent.tier.cleaner.compact.segment.min.bytes":"20971520","file.delete.delay.ms":"60000","max.message.bytes":"1048588","confluent.tier.cleaner.dual.compaction":"false","min.compaction.lag.ms":"0","message.timestamp.type":"CreateTime","preallocate":"false","confluent.placement.constraints":"","min.cleanable.dirty.ratio":"0.5","index.interval.bytes":"4096","unclean.leader.election.enable":"false","retention.bytes":"-1","delete.retention.ms":"86400000","confluent.tier.cleaner.min.cleanable.ratio":"0.75","confluent.prefer.tier.fetch.ms":"-1","confluent.key.schema.validation":"false","segment.ms":"604800000","message.timestamp.difference.max.ms":"9223372036854775807","segment.index.bytes":"10485760"},"partitions":[{"partition":0,"leader":0,"replicas":[{"broker":0,"leader":true,"in_sync":true}]},{"partition":1,"leader":0,"replicas":[{"broker":0,"leader":true,"in_sync":true}]},{"partition":2,"leader":0,"replicas":[{"broker":0,"leader":true,"in_sync":true}]}]}%
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello to get the global configuration you should do something like this

```
kafka-configs --bootstrap-server broker:9094 --command-config /path/config.properties --entity-name 100 --describe --all --entity-type brokers
```

the result will be something like this :

```
All configs for broker 100 are:
  sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.refresh.ms=3600000 sensitive=false synonyms={DEFAULT_CONFIG:sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.refresh.ms=3600000}
  remote.log.metadata.manager.listener.name=null sensitive=false synonyms={}
...
...
```